# Process Time Out Exception Queue Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, queue

Currently I'm creating a queue for process using database in laravel for processing video through an API . My video duration is 5 minutes . However my job will fail after exceeded 60 seconds time out .

I've already set variable for queue timeout somehow it still say exceed 60 seconds .

```
namespace App\Jobs;




class ProcessVideo implements ShouldQueue
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $tries = 3;

public $timeout = 300;

private $fileUrl;

private $user;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($fileUrl,$user)
{
    //

    $this->fileUrl = $fileUrl;
    $this->user = $user;


}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */

public function handle()
{

    //process webm to text 
    $client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/'
        ]);
        $audio = fopen($this->fileUrl , 'r');
        $resp = $client->request('POST', 'speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize', [
            'auth' => ['myth', 'apikey'],
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'audio/webm',
            ],
            'body' => $audio
        ]);

        $resp = $resp->getBody();

        event(new SoundSpeech($resp,$this->user));

}
}
```

Im expected queue will success after the request to api complete . somehow my job always fails cause by the timeout . Is it I need to configure the timeout from my php.ini ? or I need to use queue timeout for laravel ?